# Duplicate answer with difference link is not duplicated

Tags: discussion, answers, duplicate-answers

As I was searching for an answer in this question ([how to get complete month name from DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765441/how-to-get-complete-month-name-from-datetime)) I found these four answers:

1. [+152/0] [`DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM");` from mservidio at Jul 20 '11 at 16:46](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6765463/4519059)
2. [+19/0] [`DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM");` from Cyber Shadow at Feb 24 '15 at 8:07](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28690837/4519059)
3. [+6/0] [`DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM");` from Alex Turpin at Jul 20 '11 at 16:48](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6765482/4519059)
4. [+5/0] [`DateTime.ToString( "MMMM" )` from Stefan H at Jul 20 '11 at 16:47](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6765473/4519059)

And also 4 deleted answers those are same - with thanks to those cleaners -.

I know answers (3.) and (4.) were in a race condition so no way to blame them but will thanks if they clean SO. but what about answer(2.) that comes after 4 years?

Is it not a duplicate when it is with a new reference or it is just a comment below the answer(1.)?

Comment: Side question: What about a explanation for up-voters to don't up-vote duplicate answers? ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions with easy/obvious solutions tend to attract large numbers of similar answers. Answers #1, #3, *and* #4 were all posted within minutes of each other, so there's really nothing suspicious going on there. Just three developers who all banged out a quick solution to the asker's problem. This is one of the key *features* of Stack Overflow, and it's hard to say that they should have done anything different.

I suppose, in an ideal world, it would be nice for them to notice someone else had already posted a similar answer and delete theirs, but...race condition alert! What if all three did this, immediately deleting their own "duplicate" answers? Now we're back to the question having no answers, and the world has become a worse place.

That might sound like an exaggeration, and in some ways, I guess it is. The problem can be easily prevented by the user coming back days later and cleaning up "duplicate" answers. But that takes a pretty strongly quality-minded person, not only to motivate them to even come back and check, but *also* to motivate them to delete an answer that has gained them reputation.

Approaching it from a different way, we might ask ourselves, what is the *harm* in having three answers to a question that all say the same thing? Is it noisy? Well, maybe, but not in a bad way, since the answer you need will be at the top of the pile anyway, so you need not look through the rest of them. If you do, you can immediately see that they're saying the same thing, thus validating the correctness of the first answer you saw, all without taking an undue amount of time.

The only harm they really have is a bit of redundancy, and that's not really a harm. Sometimes it's a feature. So...while I sympathize with your desire to slash out redundancy and clean up, I think it's important to temper it a bit.

That said, there are three cases where I *do* think such answers need to be ruthlessly pruned:

1. When they are *exact* duplicates, most likely because they are code-only answers. While [there is some value in having multiple variants of the same solution, explained in different ways](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103053/how-aggressively-should-we-maintain-and-improve-very-popular-questions), two identical code blocks aren't useful to anyone. As a moderator, I will delete these. If you want to bring one to my attention, a custom flag is probably best (*"exact duplicate of existing answer <link>, adds nothing new to the question"*).
2. Late answers that *plagiarize* from an earlier answer (*i.e.*, copy its code and/or its explanation without attribution). This is essentially the case for answer #2 that you found. The problem here is not just noise; it's that the person did not merely simultaneously arrive at the same solution as other programmers. They actually just copied someone else's solution and tried to pass it off as their own. Moderators take plagiarism very seriously, and will delete answers that copy other people's work without proper attribution. Again, flagging these with a custom flag (*"possible plagiarism of <link>"*) is appropriate.
3. Questions that have received an excessively large number of answers, where redundant duplicates have started to cause problems (like pushing potentially useful alternative solutions onto another page or so far down the page they won't be seen). Moderators get an automatic flag under such circumstances, and we'll prune as we see fit. (Again, keeping case #1 in mind—don't delete answers that might add value, even if they cover similar ground.) In the case of the question you cited, there's really nothing of value being hidden, and the number of visible answers is far from excessive.

Comment: I'm agree about *race condition alert!* that I didn't suggest it, I just thanks to those who delete their duplicated answer as 4 of them done. and will thank other if others do, but my big O is why #2 has so much upvotes without any downvotes! are all those viewers/upvoters more than oldies didn't detect it as a duplicate!? any comment?

Comment: It is good to comment below duplicated answers about duplicated based on their time? It is a new answer if we add it with a new link?

Comment: There's no point in commenting below an answer if you're going to flag it for moderator attention. That just makes you a target for possible revenge downvotes. If it's something a moderator needs to handle (like plagiarism), just let us handle it. As for why the answers get upvotes, probably because people found it useful. It is a correct answer, after all. Most voters pay no attention to the age, and we generally encourage them *not* to. Votes should be based on the *content* of the post, not the time of posting or the person who posted it.